# How to paste array inside other array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

```
var str = ['a','b','c','d'];
var num = [1,2,3];
```

I want to have one array like this:

```
var strNum= ['a','b',1,2,3,'c','d'];
```

is there method for it?

Comment: Do you always want the numbers to be exactly in the middle?

Comment: if the order isn't important, you can use concat

Comment: not always, sometimes put numbers after some [i] index. Order-important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for this:

```
var str = ['a','b','c','d'];
var num = [1,2,3];

var startAt = 2;
num.forEach((number, ind)=>{
    str.splice(startAt+ind, 0, number);
});

console.log(str);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qbkqspqq/

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> The **`splice()`** method changes the content of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

with [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

> The `apply()` method calls a function with a given `this` value and `arguments` provided as an array (or an [array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Working_with_array-like_objects)).

```js
var str = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    num = [1, 2, 3],
    strNum = str.slice();

Array.prototype.splice.apply(strNum, [2, 0].concat(num));
console.log(strNum);
```

Or you could use ES6's [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

> The spread syntax allows an expression to be expanded in places where multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for array literals) or multiple variables  (for destructuring assignment) are expected.

```js
var str = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    num = [1, 2, 3],
    strNum = str.slice();

strNum.splice(2, 0, ...num);
console.log(strNum);
```

Answer (score 6):

One method is to use `splice` method. `str.splice(index, 0, item);` will insert `item` into `str` at the specified index (deleting 0 items first, that is, it's just an insert).

> The splice() method changes the content of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

View more here: [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Please try this:

```js
var str = ['a','b','c','d'];
var num = [1,2,3];
for(i in num.reverse()){
  str.splice(2, 0, num[i]);
}
console.log(str);
```

Here is another method:

```js
var str = ['a','b','c','d'];
var num = [1,2,3];
str=str.slice(0,2).concat(num).concat(str.slice(-2));
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mutating existing values is almost always a bad idea. Just concat things you need together:

```js
var str = ['a','b','c','d'];
var num = [1,2,3];

var where = 2;
var result = [].concat(
    str.slice(0, where), 
    num, 
    str.slice(where));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: My answer is not nearly as good as this

Comment: @Peachyz: yep, the OP seems to be confused with all that `splice` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice` method to split the `str` array in 2: the part before the insertion point and the part after:

```
var before = str.slice(0,2);
var after = str.slice(2);
```

Then you can use `concat` method to create the `strNum` array, concatenating the `before`, `num` and `after` arrays into one:

```
var strNum = before.concat(num).concat(after);
```

```js
var str = ['a','b','c','d'];
var num = [1,2,3];

var before = str.slice(0,2);
var after = str.slice(2);

var strNum = before.concat(num).concat(after);

console.log(strNum);
```